# Intersection of a cantor set with a regular subset

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a semi-interval split into $d$ disjoint semi-intervals, $\Omega = \bigcup_{j=1}^{d} \Delta_{j}$ , $\Delta_{j}=[\beta_{j-1},\beta_{j})$. An interval translation $T: \Omega \to \Omega$ is a map given by a translation on each $\Delta_{j}$, $T|_{\Delta_{j}}: x \mapsto x+\gamma_{j}$, the vector $(\gamma_{1}, \cdots , \gamma_d)$ is fixed. Here we consider $\Omega$ to be the interval $[0,1)$.

Define $\Omega_{0}= \Omega$, $\Omega_{n}=T\Omega_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$, and let $X$ be $\overline{\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Omega_{n}}$

Let $T$ be any interval translation map. We say that an interval $\Delta \subseteq \Omega$ is $T$-regular if there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $x \in [0,1)$ there exists $ 1 \leq n < N$ such that $T^{n}(x) \in \Delta$.

Now my question is the following statement from a lemma of a paper written by Denis Volk.

> Let $X$ is a cantor set and $\Delta$ be $T$-regular. because $\Delta$ is regular $Y=X \cap \Delta$ is non-empty cantor set.

Is this easy to see that?

Comment: Can $\gamma_\bullet$ be any value?

Comment: @FShrike Yes $\gamma_{j}$ could be any real number.

Comment: I suppose one should define what a Cantor set is.

Comment: @FShrike I think it does not matter what the space $X$ is. let $X$ is a cantor set now could we say the intersection of a cantor set with a regular set is again a cantor set?

Comment: If we say "Cantor set" means "closed, perfect and nowhere dense", then the intersection with a regular set is still nowhere dense, but we cannot conclude it is compact (unless the regular set is closed), and the intersection could easily have isolated points.

Comment: Is $x \in [0,1)$ should be $x  \in \Delta$? Otherwise I don't understand where the interval $[0,1($ comes from.

Comment: @EtienneBfx The whole interval $[0,1)$ is divided to some subintervals named $\Delta_j$ then each $x \in [0,1)$ belongs to some $\Delta_j$ and is moved by a special $\gamma_j$.